# How do I find records out of order - SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table with an ID Identity column, some data, and a datestamp.  Like this:

```
1   data    5/1/2013 12:30
2   data    5/2/2013 15:32
3   data    5/2/2013 16:45
4   data    5/3/2013 9:32
5   data    5/5/2013 8:21
6   data    5/4/2013 9:36
7   data    5/6/2013 11:42
```

How do I write a query that will show me the one record that is timestamped 5/4?  The table has millions of records.  I've done some searching, but I don't know what to call what I'm searching for.  :/

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using. In 2012 this is pretty easy using the `lag()` function.

Comment: How do you determine that it isnt the record id 5 which is misplaced ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare @t table(id int, bla char(4), timestamp datetime)
insert @t values
(1,'data','5/1/2013 12:30'),
(2,'data','5/2/2013 15:32'),
(3,'data','5/2/2013 16:45'),
(4,'data','5/3/2013 9:32'),
(5,'data','5/5/2013 8:21'),
(6,'data','5/4/2013 9:36'),
(7,'data','5/6/2013 11:42')

select timestamp
from
(
  select rn1 = row_number() over (order by id), 
  rn2 = row_number() over (order by timestamp), timestamp
  from @t 
) a
where rn1 not in (rn2, rn2-1)
```

Comment: may be `rn1 > rn2` will be enough?

Comment: @RomanPekar it could be enough, it is kind of how the question is interpreted. This way it will be very picky with the rows accepted

Comment: I'm running this now, but there are more than 10 million records.  We'll see...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

in 2008 r2, this would be a way

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(id INT , ladate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, '2013-05-01')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, '2013-05-02')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, '2013-05-03')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, '2013-05-05')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, '2013-05-04')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, '2013-05-06')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, '2013-05-07')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (8, '2013-05-08')
```

--I added the records in the sort order but if not just make sure you are sorted in the query

```
SELECT t2.ladate FROM @Table T1
INNER JOIN @Table T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id + 1
INNER JOIN @Table t3 ON t2.id = t3.id + 1
WHERE t3.ladate < t2.ladate AND t2.ladate > t1.ladate
```

-- I made the assumption that your Id are all there, 1,2,3,4,5.... none missing... if there are rownumbers missing, you can use row_number()

Comment: Actually, with the ID column being automatic, and with over 10 million records, there is only one ID that is missing, and it was from 9 years ago, could have been from testing

Comment: the answer from t-clausen is better, i can't vote mine down sadly ;)

Comment: I didn't try yours because the other answer was first (not by time, but listed on the page)...  But just because another answer is better doesn't mean this one should be voted down.  ;)

Comment: ;)  Not only that, but with written sarcasm, I'm good at writing it, but not so good at picking it up.